# Trying to change Case of particular character in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to change a **case** of particular character in a cell but i think i am missing very small thing in it.

Eg.
The cell has value '*A for Apple and GORILLA wears pajama*'

so i am trying to change case of individual 'A' into lower case 'a'.

Now there are 3 scenarios:

1. A can be in **Starting** of cell.
2. A can be in **Middle** of cell.
3. A can be in **End** of cell.

for the middle one I have solution:

```
Activecell.value = Replace(Activecell.value," A "," a ",vbTextCompare)
```

but for other 2 when I'm trying to do change other A's also changing, for example:

```
Activecell.value = Replace(Activecell.value,"A ","a ",vbTextCompare)
```

this is giving answer '*a for Apple and GORILLa wears pajama*'
wherein I'm trying to get '*a for Apple and GORILLA wears pajama*'

my code is

```
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -cnt).Value = "" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -cnt1).Value = ""
actc = ActiveCell.Value
If actc = "" Then
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Else
ActiveCell.Value = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, " m ", " m ", , , vbTextCompare)
ActiveCell.Value = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, " cm ", " cm ", , , vbTextCompare)
ActiveCell.Value = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, " dm ", " dm ", , , vbTextCompare)
ActiveCell.Value = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, " mm ", " mm ", , , vbTextCompare)
ActiveCell.Value = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, " mg ", " mg ", , , vbTextCompare)
End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace only the "A " in the beginning check this in particular.

```
If Left$(ActiveCell.Value, 2) = "A " Then 
    ActiveCell.Value = "a" & Right$(ActiveCell.Value, Len(ActiveCell.Value) - 1))
End If
```

Accordingly for the " A" in the end (Even if I don't know about sentences ending with " A")

```
If Right$(ActiveCell.Value, 2) = " A" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = Left$(ActiveCell.Value, Len(ActiveCell.Value) - 1)) & "a"
End If
```

Comment: Hi @peh, Thanks for your effort. but in actual there are more than 5k rows in which i am running loop and it is not mandatory that the sentence  would be same and there are around 11 characters for which i want to change case.

Comment: @MandeepRandhawa Please don't add code in comments (this is not readable). All parts of your question have to be in the original question. Please move your code into the question and ask a proper question to it.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA `Replace` function will replace **ALL** instances of the substring in the target string.

To specify beginning and/or end of the string, you can test for the presence of the substring and, if it is present, use a different function (I chose to use the Replace Worksheet function) to replace only that character. Examine the following code snippet for an example.

```
With ActiveCell
    If .Value Like "A*" Then .Value = WorksheetFunction.Replace(.Value, 1, 1, "a") 'Beginning only
    If .Value Like "*A" Then .Value = WorksheetFunction.Replace(.Value, Len(.Value), 1, "a") 'End only
End With
```

If, on the other hand, you want the sentence to start (or end) with the *word* **A**, implying there is a space after (or before) the **A**, then change the `Like` pattern to reflect that  `"A *"` or `* A"

If all of those substrings are, in fact, words, and you want to replace them all in each `ActiveCell`, you can either construct multiple loops along the format of what you are doing, or you could use `Regular Expressions`.

For example, the following will replace all instances of the capitals you have indicated with their lower case equivalents, whether they are at the beginning, middle or end.

The macro first matches all of the instances of the different words in `sPat`, and then cycles through the sentence to replace them.  (Note that we must go from last to first in the loop, since the lengths of each word may not be the same).

```
Option Explicit
Sub doit()
  ActiveCell = replaceCaps(ActiveCell)
End Sub

Function replaceCaps(ByRef S As String)
    Const sPat As String = "\b(?:A|M|CM|DM|MM|MG)\b"
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim I As Long

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = False
    .Pattern = sPat
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        For I = MC.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            S = WorksheetFunction.Replace(S, MC(I).firstindex + 1, Len(MC(I)), LCase(MC(I)))
        Next I
        replaceCaps = S
    Else
        replaceCaps = S
    End If
End With      

End Function
```